# Confusion Regarding The Fourier Series In Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, signals

I am currently studying DSP and i'm using the Matlab software package to work my way through the the problems. I am currently just starting to attempt to learn about the fourier series and am having trouble with the following problem.

> Generate an 100hz triangle wave using Fourier Series.

Now, i cant quite understand this part of the problem about using the fourier series.

I have generated a 100hz triangle wave with the following matlab code:

```
t = 0:1/10000:1;
f=100;
x1 = sawtooth(2*pi*f*t, 0.5);
x2 = fft(x1);
plot(t,x1); 
axis([0 0.10 -1 1]); 
grid on;
```

Now what code would i use within matlab to plot the fourier series of this triangle wave?

Thanks to anyone who may have some input for this particular problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think what the question is asking is for you to figure out the 'a' and 'b' coefficients and then generate the sawtooth wave by summing sines and cosines at the appropriate frequencies.  It's not too hard to find the Fourier coefficients for a sawtooth wave online, but I encourage you to work it out and use that to check your answer :)

Then do something like this

```
n_harmonics = 10;
n = zeros(1, n_harmonics);
a = ?;  % for you to figure out - probably a function of n
b = ?;  % same idea

t = linspace(0, 2*pi);
x = zeros(size(t));
for nx = 1 : n,
    x = x + a(nx)*cos(nx*t) + b(nx)*sin(nx*t);
end
plot(t, x)
```

Note the Fourier series is not the same thing as the Fourier transform, which is what `fft` is estimating.  Most texts on signal processing will start with the Fourier series and build on that to get to the Fourier transform.  Note also that there are tons of important and subtle differences when moving from continuous time to discrete time.  Again, most textbooks will probably start with continuous time and then use that as a basis to introduce the discrete-time concepts.